# Create Node and Set a value in a relationship Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a node and add a new relationship setting a value but I keep on getting the same error every time:

```
Invalid input '"': expected whitespace, comment, an identifier, UnsignedDecimalInteger, a property key name or '}' (line 6, column 3 (offset: 263))
"  "Value": "2024-02-06T11:16:02.09Z""
```

This is my query, can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? If I send this query in code, then it runs successfully, I can't determined what is wrong with this.

Many thanks.

```
MATCH (n:Node),(additionalDate:AdditionalDate)
WHERE (n.Id = "xxxx1111xxxx11")
AND (additionalDate.DateType = "1")
CREATE (additionalDate)-[additionalDateOf:AdditionalDateOf]->(n)
SET additionalDateOf = {
  "Value": "2024-02-06T11:16:02.09Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set like this:

```
MATCH (n:NodeA),(additionalDate:AdditionalDate)
WHERE (n.Id = "xxxx1111xxxx11")
AND (additionalDate.DateType = "1")
CREATE (additionalDate)-[additionalDateOf:AdditionalDateOf]->(n)
SET additionalDateOf.Value = "2024-02-06T11:16:02.09Z"
```

For:

```
MERGE (n:NodeA {Id:"xxxx1111xxxx11"})
MERGE (additionalDate:AdditionalDate {DateType:"1"})
```

If I add a return to the query above I get:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│n                              │additionalDate                   │additionalDateOf                                      │
╞═══════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│(:NodeA {Id: "xxxx1111xxxx11"})│(:AdditionalDate {DateType: "1"})│[:AdditionalDateOf {Value: "2024-02-06T11:16:02.09Z"}]│
└───────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

As @nimrod-serok suggests, you can use the dot property reference syntax to set the `Value` property of `additionalDateOf`.

Alternatively, you can just remove the double quotes from the key:

```cypher
MATCH (n:Node),(additionalDate:AdditionalDate)
WHERE (n.Id = "xxxx1111xxxx11")
AND (additionalDate.DateType = "1")
CREATE (additionalDate)-[additionalDateOf:AdditionalDateOf]->(n)
SET additionalDateOf = {
  Value: "2024-02-06T11:16:02.09Z"
}
```

The property key-values you are assigning to the relationship are a map where the keys are identifiers. You were using the JSON data format where the keys are specified as strings.

As a third option, you can inline the property specification in the `CREATE` clause:

```cypher
MATCH (n:Node),(additionalDate:AdditionalDate)
WHERE (n.Id = "xxxx1111xxxx11")
AND (additionalDate.DateType = "1")
CREATE (additionalDate)-[additionalDateOf:AdditionalDateOf 
                          {Value: "2024-02-06T11:16:02.09Z"}]->(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @FinbarGood's answer, you may want to use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead of [CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/) in order to avoid creating duplicate relationships:

```
MATCH (n:Node), (additionalDate:AdditionalDate)
WHERE (n.Id = "xxxx1111xxxx11") AND (additionalDate.DateType = "1")
MERGE (additionalDate)-[additionalDateOf:AdditionalDateOf]->(n)
ON CREATE
  SET additionalDateOf = {
    Value: "2024-02-06T11:16:02.09Z"
  }
```